# Keras custom ImageDataGenerator to load images batch wise (with images segmented as patches)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have been trying to train a network consisting of a VGG16network followed by some LSTM layers. Since my images are quite big and because VGG16 do not scale with image size i decided to break my images into small patches and train an LSTM to read an image piece by piece. Since I have a large data set i need the model to load the data batch wise. I have made an attempt to build a custom data generator, however i am not sure my implementation is correct since i don't know how to see which images the model has loaded while it is training. I also don't know how to make it adaptable if i have a different number of patches at each epoch.

My dataset is organised as followed:

```
    data|
        |---train|
                 |---class1|
                           |---image1|
                                     |---im1_patch1.tif
                                     |---im1_patch2.tif
                                     ...            
                                     |---im1_patch352.tif   
                           |---image2|
                                     |---im2_patch1.tif
                                     |---im2_patch2.tif
                                     ...            
                                     |---im2_patch352.tif   
                 |---class2|
                           |---image3|
                                     |---im3_patch1.tif
                                     |---im3_patch2.tif
                                     ...            
                                     |---im3_patch352.tif   
                           |---image4|
                                     |---im4_patch1.tif
                                     |---im4_patch2.tif
                                     ...            
                                     |---im4_patch352.tif
```

As you can see my images are already broken into patches and i would like to load them batch wise such that my tensor X for each batch as the following dimension: [batch_size, n_patches, w, h, n_channels]. batch_size is the number of image at each epoch, n_patches is the number of patches per image, w and h are dimension of each patch (fixed) and n_channels number of channels of each patch (fixed to 3)

I first have some questions,

1. Does it make sense to have a batch_size > 1 for each epoch? I guess it doesn't make sense if my images have a different number of patches, am I right?
2. can I feed my LSTM with a different number of patches for each epoch? for example if my images have different number of patches. I am not sure how to do it.
3. Let's say i load one image (consisting of npatches) per epoch, what happen when the number of epoch is bigger than the number of images? Is the loading restarting from 0 (it doesn't seem in my code)? may be I should pick images randomly what do you think?

My network architecture is the following:

```
vgg = VGG16(
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
)

for layer in vgg.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(vgg, input_shape=(npatches, w, h, nchannels)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten(name="flatten")))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4096, activation="relu")))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4096, activation="relu")))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten(name="flatten")))

model.add(LSTM(264, activation='tanh',return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='tanh',return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='tanh',return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

Finally, my attempt to build a custom image generator:

```
def LoadImages(folder, batch_size, npatches):

    batch_start = 0
    batch_end = n_patches-1
    epoch_id = 0
        
    files =  list(paths.list_images(folder))
    n_images = len(files)
    
    StopCriteria = n_images/(batch_size*n_patches) 
    
    while True:
        
        while epoch_id < StopCriteria:
            
            patch_id = 0
            X = np.empty([batch_size, n_patches, 224, 224, 3])
            Y = np.empty([batch_size, n_patches])
        
            for image_path in files[batch_start:batch_end]:
                img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_path,color_mode="rgb")
                input_arr = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
        
                X[epoch_id,patch_id,:,:,:] = input_arr
                
                if image_path.split("\\")[-3].split('/')[-1] == 'long':
                    Y[epoch_id,patch_id] = 0
                if image_path.split("\\")[-3].split('/')[-1] == 'short':
                    Y[epoch_id,patch_id] = 1
                    
                patch_id += 1
                
            yield (X,Y)
                
            batch_start += batch_size + n_patches-1
            batch_end += batch_size + n_patches-1
            
            epoch_id += 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are the sizes of the image? Why not just resize them instead of breaking the image up?

Comment: not to lose information in the image

Comment: images are about 3000px by 3000px

Comment: Either way VGG16 only accepts images in 224x224x3 input shape. You would not be losing information in the image unless you are converting them to grayscale from RGB.

Comment: i am not sure to understand why wouldn't i lose information by rescaling? this is why i use LSTM after processing my 224*224 patches with VGG16